# Pass css ::after content as specific word from class name

Tags: html, css

I want to pass CSS `::after` content as a specific word from its class element.

If class names are "language-css", "language-html", etc, in this case, I want to pass the content as the word after the "-".

```css
code::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<code class="language-css"> some code here </code>
<code class="language-html"> some code here </code>
<code class="language-javascript"> some code here </code>
```

I know this returns the whole text from the CSS class, does CSS support any split function as JavaScript does?

Comment: No, CSS does not support this. Put the text you want in a `data-attribute` and use this instead.

Comment: alternativly you could also just declare the text in CSS directly like: `code.language-css::before { content: "CSS"; }`

Comment: the element and class name generated by a third-party plugin, so can we work unless script.

Comment: @tacoshy using code.language-css::after is very hard, because there're lot of languages in the loop.

Comment: while generating your class name, you can also generate a data-attribute striped of  `language-` and instead using the class for the pseudo content, use the  data-attribute . It could be: `data-langage="html" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can hack is with some negative `text-indent` if the prefix is always the same. The `code` element is using a monospace font so it's easy using `ch` unit

```css
code::before {
  content: attr(class);
  display:inline-block;
  text-indent:-9ch; /* adjust this based on your real case */
  clip-path:inset(0); /* hide the overflow */
}
```

```html
<code class="language-css"> some code here </code>
<code class="language-html"> some code here </code>
<code class="language-javascript"> some code here </code>
```

Comment: That's a really nice solution, this will work in this case since it will be only 1 line. This won't work with multi-line text (just as an info for everyone else stumbling on this great solution)

Comment: @cloned it does work with multi-line text, reduce your screen width and the text will wrap naturally

Comment: You are right, it really works with multiline text. Thought it will cut 10 characters off from each line. I stand corrected, thanks for the clarification. Nice solution!